# zoom text with scrolling the page on Wix

Tags: javascript, velo

I want to create a page on my website when I scroll down the page, the text increases its size
I use Wix to build my website, I have this code in Javascript I have to convert it to Velo in order to work on my Wix website.
I am new at Velo coding, I don't know what I should change in my code.

my code:

```
  $w.onReady(function () {
    const zoomElement = $w('#workspace');
    let zoom = 1;
    const ZOOM_SPEED = 0.1;
    
    document.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {
      if (e.deltaY > 0) {
        zoomElement.style.transform = `scale(${(zoom += ZOOM_SPEED)})`;
      } else {
        zoomElement.style.transform = `scale(${(zoom -= ZOOM_SPEED)})`;
      }
     });
    });
```

I get two error Wix don't recognize `document` and `style`

Answer (score 1):

Wix does not expose access to the document object or the transform function through its APIs.

This is doable in Velo, but in a different manner. The are a number of ways to do this, but I would suggest this. First you would need to setup a function to run at regular intervals to get the vertical position on the page. Then you can use the wix-animations API to scale the text appropriately.